# Cutting an array?

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to take a number `N` from user and split the array according to that number and save the new elements in new one.

For example, when the user enters 2, and I have an array like

```
["alameeer", "alameer", "alameer", "alameer", "alameer", "ashraf"]
```

the result will be

```
["alameeer", "alameer"], ["alameeer", "alameer"], ["alameeer", "ashraf"]
```

When N equals 3

```
["alameeer", "alameer", "alameeer"], ["alameeer", "alameer", "alameeer"]
```

I tried below code but it is very static and very bad performance and I don't know how to change it.

```
string str = UserCorpus.TrimEnd();
string[] Oops = str.Split(' ', ',', '!');
int stringCounter = Oops.Length;
string[] holder = new string[10];
for (int i = 0; i < stringCounter - 2; i++)
{
    holder[i] = Oops[i] + Oops[i + 1] + Oops[i + 2]; 
}
```

Comment: "very bad performance" it's probably not a problem here. `holder` is a 10 element array, you will not be able to notice your "bad performance".
You have other problems here: what if `stringcounter` is 20? where do you consider user input (2, 3 or whatever?)

Comment: Yep , I noticed that and here i supposed that stringcounter less than holder size ! How can i make that dynamic accepting from user then divide!!?

Comment: Your post is insanely confusing. I stumped to this question earlier and commented to it, comment has been deleted and dislikes gone? If you re-uploaded this question again with a poor format to avoid more dislikes and auto-delete comments & answers, you should consider taking a look at your question format. -1

Comment: I think i give an example to you if you didn't  understand this question format , and didn't  understand my example twice , i think you already have a problem!

Comment: @AlameerAshraf I understood your problem, actually I was writing an answer meanwhile you commented that. Your old format was very messy and hard to read for any human being.

Comment: Ok thank you bro ! I realized that and rewrite the question again to be easy to understand . Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be worry about bad performance here. What you are trying to do cant become better than `O(n)`.

How ever i suggest you use Batch from MoreLinq. its also written by jon skeet, any questions? ;)

```
string[] array = new[] {"alameeer", "alameer", "alameer", "alameer", "alameer", "ashraf"};
int cut = 2;
var result = array.Batch(cut, piece => string.Join(" ", piece)).ToArray();
```

Any way if you want to write your own implementation you can do this. which works for any cut length and array length. (I doubt this one be `O(n)` because i think `Skip(i)` is not `O(1)`)

```
string[] array = new[] {"alameeer", "alameer", "alameer", "alameer", "alameer", "ashraf"};
int cut = 2;

string[] result = new string[(int)Math.Ceiling(array.Length / (double)cut)];
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < array.Length; i += cut, j++)
{
    result[j] = string.Join(" ", array.Skip(i).Take(cut));
}
```

If you dont want to use Linq at all. (`O(n)`)

```
string[] array = new[] { "alameeer", "alameer", "alameer", "alameer", "alameer", "ashraf" };
int cut = 4;

string[] result = new string[(int)Math.Ceiling(array.Length / (double)cut)];
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < array.Length; i += cut, j++)
{
    string[] temp = new string[Math.Min(cut, array.Length)];
    for (int k = i; k < i + cut && k < array.Length; k++)
    {
        temp[k - i] = array[k];
    }
    result[j] = string.Join(" ", temp).Trim();
}
```

Comment: can you explain to me what the function of that code because i can't understand it ! thanks 
'result[j] = string.Join(" ", array.Skip(i).Take(cut));'

Comment: sure, imagine this array. `a , b , c , d , e`. now this linq code `array.Take(2)` gives you `a , b` basically i takes first 2 items. this code `array.Skip(1).Take(2)` will give you `b , c`. this one skips the first element and takes 2 items. another example. `Skip(3).Take(50)` will give you `d , e`. so this one skips first 3 items. and tries to take 50 items but there is only 2 items left so it will only return that 2 items ;) @AlameerAshraf

Comment: this part. `string.Join(" ", array)` will join the array with spaces. so if you have array `a,b,c`. it will give you `"a b c"`. this code `string.Join("_", array)` will give you this string `"a_b_c"`

Comment: Note that `Skip` and `Take` are linq queries that will give you `IEnumerable` and not array. btw the `string.Join` works with it too. you can read tutorials about  `IEnumerable` from internet  but thats a bit hard and tricky ;)

Comment: thank you so much really i appreciate your effort here !